# Event "editable-save.bs.table" isn't working in bootstrap-table

Tags: jquery, events, x-editable, bootstrap-table

I'm using bootstrap-table and it's extension table editable (taken from x-editable). Two given events for this extension (editable-init.bs.table & editable-save.bs.table) aren't working. Or I've understand this feature incorrectly.

Anyone uses bootstrap-table with table editable? Which selector do you use for method on()?

Please help me.

P.S.: events from x-editable aren't working too

Answer (score 1):

Pls include u code that didn't works.

My suggestion :

Js fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/36/

Documentation :

http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#events

Sample :

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    onEventName: function (arg1, arg2, ...) {
        // ...
    }
});

$('#table').on('event-name.bs.table', function (e, arg1, arg2, ...) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: link redirects, consider fixing

Answer (score 1):

This is not my code, I just stripped internals and added alert. It seem to work!

```
$(document).on('editable-save.bs.table', '#table', function (e, field, row, old, $el) {
  alert("Here!");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Barmaley13/e3nk137y/21607/

Make sure to include js scripts in this order:

1. bootstrap-editable.js
2. bootstrap-table-editable.js

That was my mistake. Best of luck!